# How do I load a URL using NSItemProvider's new Async loadItem method?

Tags: swift, foundation

I am having difficulty grabbing a fileURL in a `DropDelegate` in SwiftUI, when dragging a file from my desktop into my app.

I am using the async loadItem call on `NSItemProvider` which returns an `NSSecureCoding`. I assumed that I could cast the result to an NSURL but it always fails.

```
let url = try await (urlProvider
    .loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.url.identifier) as? NSURL
```

If I try to force the cast I get the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.__NSSwiftData' to 'NSURL'.
```

I am successfully using the same call and casting to an NSDictionary elsewhere in my code.

This is in Xcode 13.4, Swift 5.
I have read access to user selected files in my sandbox capabilities.

Can anyone help point out what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to cast to `Data` and then construct the `URL` from that:

```
if let data = try await urlProvider
    .loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.fileURL.identifier) as? Data {
    url = URL(dataRepresentation: data, relativeTo: nil) }
```

Comment: This was beyond helpful — thanks for sharing!