# Impossible to parse result for await itemProvider.loadItem for URL

Tags: ios, swift, plist

My code goes like this:

```swift
let item = try await itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.url.identifier, options: nil)

if let data = item as? Data  {
    do {
        if let plist = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [String: Any] {
            print(plist)
        } else if let url = URL(dataRepresentation: data, relativeTo: nil) {
            print(url.absoluteString)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I copy and paste the URL from iOS 17 Safari using the SwiftUI PasteButton when testing this.

The plist parsing is not working, and the data gets parsed as URL, but I get something that reminds more on plist.

So I have tested for today's first story on Engadget, the test URL was: https://www.engadget.com/microsoft-surface-laptop-studio-2-hands-on-more-ports-and-a-much-needed-spec-bump-171733141.html

After parsing it as URL, I get:

> `bplist00%C2%A3%01%02%03_%10yhttps://www.engadget.com/microsoft-surface-laptop-studio-2-hands-on-more-ports-and-a-much-needed-spec-bump-171733141.htmlP%C3%91%04%05Utitle_%10RMicrosoft%20Surface%20Laptop%20Studio%202%20hands-on:%20More%20ports%20and%20a%20much-needed%20spec%20bump%08%0C%C2%88%C2%89%C2%8C%C2%92%00%00%00%00%00%00%01%01%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%06%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%C3%A7`

Again this looks like plist, but at least with the code above doesn't parse.

It is likely that something has changed in iOS as according to this old thread simple parsing to URL should work: [How do I load a URL using NSItemProvider's new Async loadItem method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72320926/how-do-i-load-a-url-using-nsitemproviders-new-async-loaditem-method)

How to handle this?

Comment: What's the actual value of `data` that you get?

Comment: @Alexander If I do print(data) I get the same as above

Comment: Okay, I think I was misled`After parsing it as URL, I get:`. So the snippet you show is the `data` _before_ any parsing (as a plist or URL), right? Hmmm, It looks like a plausible binary plist payload. What does the error say?

Comment: @Alexander Actually this doesn't cause exception, just if goes further. Technically it could be that something other than [String: Any] is returned, but that would be strange in its own way. I'll check that.

Comment: Try to add `var format: PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat = .binary` and `format: &format`?

Comment: @Alexander OK, the strange part is that plist is created and it is: plist (
    "https://www.engadget.com/microsoft-surface-laptop-studio-2-hands-on-more-ports-and-a-much-needed-spec-bump-171733141.html",
    "",
        {
        title = "Microsoft Surface Laptop Studio 2 hands-on: More ports and a much-needed spec bump";
    }
). However I guess that it is not [String : Any]???

Comment: @Larme, thanks but as said above thanks to Alexender I have figured out that plist is actually being created, just its cast to [String, Any] fails. So the problem lies there, that is very close to the solution just I need to find the proper type.

Comment: Seems to be an `array` to me: `as [String]`, or just a String: `as? String`

Comment: @Larme it is actually [Any]. I posted the answer below...

Comment: I tried your code with provided URL, and I got a String back, not a bplist, strange....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate the help from others. The answer is that plist needs to be casted to `[Any]` instead of `[String: Any]`

Comment: And such are the dangers of discarding errors with `try?` :/